# get unique key values from an array of array of hash in ruby to perform grouping

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have an array as below:

```
arr = [
  [
    { :pm => 38, :scs => 5, :bg => "#66ffff", :impact => nil, :focus => 9 },
    { :pm => 38, :scs => 6, :bg => "#66ffff", :impact => 2, :focus => 9 },
    { :pm => 38, :scs => 7, :bg => "#66ffff", :impact => nil, :focus => 9 }
  ],
  [
    { :pm => 26, :scs => 5, :bg => "#ffe18b", :impact => 2, :focus => 2 },
    { :pm => 26, :scs => 6, :bg => "#ffe18b", :impact => 1, :focus => 2 },
    { :pm => 26, :scs => 7, :bg => "#ffe18b", :impact => nil, :focus => 2 }
  ],
  [
    { :pm => 39, :scs => 5, :bg => "#ffe18b", :impact => nil, :focus => 2 },
    { :pm => 39, :scs => 6, :bg => "#ffe18b", :impact => nil, :focus => 2 },
    { :pm => 39, :scs => 7, :bg => "#ffe18b", :impact => nil, :focus => 2 }
  ],
  [
    { :pm => 25, :scs => 5, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => 1, :focus => 4 },
    { :pm => 25, :scs => 6, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => 2, :focus => 4 },
    { :pm => 25, :scs => 7, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => 1, :focus => 4 }
  ],
  [
    { :pm => 34, :scs => 5, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => nil, :focus => 4 },
    { :pm => 34, :scs => 6, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => nil, :focus => 4 },
    { :pm => 34, :scs => 7, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => nil, :focus => 4 }
  ],
  [
    { :pm => 23, :scs => 5, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => 2, :focus => 4 },
    { :pm => 23, :scs => 6, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => 1, :focus => 4 },
    { :pm => 23, :scs => 7, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => 1, :focus => 4 }
  ],
  [
    { :pm => 32, :scs => 5, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => nil, :focus => 4 },
    { :pm => 32, :scs => 6, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => 2, :focus => 4 },
    { :pm => 32, :scs => 7, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => 1, :focus => 4 }
  ],
  [
    { :pm => 17, :scs => 5, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => nil, :focus => 4 },
    { :pm => 17, :scs => 6, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => 2, :focus => 4 },
    { :pm => 17, :scs => 7, :bg => "#ffffe5", :impact => 1, :focus => 4 }
  ]
]
```

I need to get the value of the key `:focus` uniquely for grouping the above list based on the focus value.

Comment: What's your expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this would do?

```
arr.flatten.group_by {|elem| elem[:focus]}
```

If you just need the uniq `focus` values,

```
arr.flatten.map {|elem| elem[:focus] }.uniq
```